# Not auto collapse when creating sub item in menu of Bootstrap Adminlte template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all I am a developer, not a designer.

I am building Codeigniter project using [Adminlte](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) template. Now I face a problem. I will try to explain it using screenshots.

**Screenshot 01 : This is the menu**

[image]

**Screenshot 02 : I am going to click User List Item**

[image]

---

**Question** : When I click "User List" I am expecting that page menu also same as **screenshot 02.**(I mean user mangment menu should be open / collapse auto automatically). But I am getting interface like **screenshot 1**. How do I solve it?

Note : Please asked if you need some additional codes of my site because I don't know what codes should I put here.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>

      <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>User Management</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/user/list'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> User List</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/user/add'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Add New User</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>



      <li><a href="../../documentation/index.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Messages</span></a></li>

      <li><a href="../../documentation/index.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Logout</span></a></li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding class "active" to the list item which needs to be stayed open.

```
<li class="active">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add active class to li tag to work.