# Bootstrap Adminlte template - Auto collapse not working when create sub items on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building Codeigniter project using [Adminlte](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) template. Now I face a problem. I will try to explain it using screenshots.

**Screenshot 01 : This is the menu**

[image]

**Screenshot 02 : I am going to click User List Item**

[image]

---

**Question** : When I click "User List" I am expecting that page menu also same as **screenshot 02.**(I mean user mangment menu should be open / collapse auto automatically). But I am getting interface like **screenshot 1**. How do I solve it?

Note : Please asked if you need some additional codes of my site because I don't know what codes should I put here.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>

      <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>User Management</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/user/list'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> User List</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/user/add'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Add New User</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>



      <li><a href="../../documentation/index.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Messages</span></a></li>

      <li><a href="../../documentation/index.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Logout</span></a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: The page is reloading after changing url. You have to add the active CSS class to the menu to show it as the current active menu.

Comment: @cgTag Should I do it manually? :-( I mean reading all URL using PHP and should I programitically set active class? I have to use lots of if conditions on my sidebar... I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes. Basically that is the easiest way. You can do this work in JavaScript but out of the box AdminLTE has very basic JavaScript logic. There is no logic for routes to active sidebar menus. If you look at the the demo for LTE each page includes the sidebar with different active menu items. At least you already have PHP you can use to write the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with this question you asked before? I see you have the answer there.

[Not auto collapse when creating sub item in menu of Bootstrap Adminlte template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130361/not-auto-collapse-when-creating-sub-item-in-menu-of-bootstrap-adminlte-template/)